# need to continue after the MQ exception MQRC_UNKNOWN_OBJECT_NAME in java( Sprinngboot)

Tags: java, spring-boot, ibm-mq

I have following method to send a message to MQ , when the queue name is incorrect it throws MQRC_UNKNOWN_OBJECT_NAME error, but I want to pass the custom error (something like "queue name is not found") and let the user to continue with a correct queue name. I tried to capture the message send not successful scenario by returning the mqSend() method as false. but it doesn't work as I expected. Can someone help me out here? ( please note I'm setting the required MQ properties(QUEUE_NAME,QMGR,CHANNEL,HOST,PORT) separately.

```
    public boolean mqSend()
    {
        

        

    
        String APP_USER = ""; // User name that application uses to connect to MQ
        String APP_PASSWORD = ""; // Password that the application uses to connect to MQ

        
        // Variables
        JMSContext context = null;
        Destination destination = null;
        JMSProducer producer = null;
        //JMSConsumer consumer = null;
        
        
        try {
            // Create a connection factory
            JmsFactoryFactory ff = JmsFactoryFactory.getInstance(WMQConstants.WMQ_PROVIDER);
            JmsConnectionFactory cf = ff.createConnectionFactory();

            // Set the properties
            cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_HOST_NAME, HOST);
            cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_PORT, PORT);
            cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CHANNEL, CHANNEL);
            cf.setIntProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_CONNECTION_MODE, WMQConstants.WMQ_CM_CLIENT);
            cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_QUEUE_MANAGER, QMGR);
            cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_APPLICATIONNAME, "Manual message publihser");
            cf.setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.USER_AUTHENTICATION_MQCSP, true);
            cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.USERID, APP_USER);
            cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.PASSWORD, APP_PASSWORD);
            
            //cf.setStringProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_SSL_CIPHER_SUITE, "*TLS12");

            // Create JMS objects
            context = cf.createContext();
            
            destination = context.createQueue("queue:///" + QUEUE_NAME);
            ((MQDestination)destination).setTargetClient(JMSC.MQJMS_CLIENT_NONJMS_MQ);
            

            //long uniqueNumber = System.currentTimeMillis() % 1000;
            //TextMessage message = context.createTextMessage("Your lucky number today is " + uniqueNumber);
            TextMessage message = context.createTextMessage(MESSAGE);
            
            
            producer = context.createProducer();
            producer.send(destination, message);
            System.out.println("<INFO> : Sent message details:\n" + message);

            //consumer = context.createConsumer(destination); // autoclosable
            //String receivedMessage = consumer.receiveBody(String.class, 15000); // in ms or 15 seconds

            //System.out.println("\nReceived message:\n" + receivedMessage);

                        context.close();
return true;
            //recordSuccess();
        } catch (JMSException jmsex) {
            //recordFailure(jmsex);
            System.out.println("JMS/MQ error OCCURED!!!!");
return false;
        }
        

        //System.exit(status);
        
        
    }
```

Comment: Does the value you have for **_QUEUE_NAME_** actually exist in the queue manager?

Comment: How would you know the correct queue name?   Are you just wanting to capture the error and reprompt for the name?   Why not wrap the `createQueue` or `producer.send` (can't remember which would produce the `MQRC_UNKNOWN_OBJECT_NAME`) in its own try/catch?

Comment: @roger ,this works with the happy scenario(when inserted an available queue) without any issue, I just want to capture if the queue is not present scenario.

Comment: @JoshMC the idea of this tool is to use application testing, so testers probably know the destination queue.

Comment: See my suggestion above.  Would this not work?

Comment: @JoshMC  thanks a lot!! I found where it triggered it from. it is producer.send indeed. I can continue with it now.. thanks again

Comment: If @JoshMC 's answer answered your question, can you please mark it as answered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap the `producer.send` call in its own try/catch and look for `MQRC_UNKNOWN_OBJECT_NAME` or other errors such as `MQRC_NOT_AUTHORIZED` or `MQRC_Q_FULL`.